# PoolLedgerTimeout in Hyperledger Indy

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

**Problem:**

I have cloned the Hyperledger-Indy SDK repository and then I try to run the nodeJs sample Firstly I issued the command `npm run ledger: start` then I issue npm install and then npm run start inside the nodejs folder. After that I got

```
> samples@1.0.0 start /home/tharindu/indy-sdk/samples/nodejs
> node src/main.js

gettingStarted.js -> started
Open Pool Ledger: pool1
done
(node:4013) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: IndyError: PoolLedgerTimeout
    at Object.callback (/home/tharindu/indy-sdk/samples/nodejs/node_modules/indy-sdk/src/wrapIndyCallback.js:15:10)
(node:4013) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4013) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This error on the terminal. Can someone help me to solve this issue?. I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem but I was unable to find out a solution to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share the details of your development environment such as OS type, OS version, NodeJs version, nvm version etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because you didn't start the pool ledger of hiperledger Indy.
I can replicate the problem.

[https://imgur.com/a/AK0WlV9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQq8T.png)

I already installed the docker which contain the ledge,so I use docker for run the pool ledger, using the command:

```
sudo docker run -itd -p 9701-9708:9701-9708 indy_pool
```

In case you dont have installed the docker and have runed ledger i recomend you this link, it's only few steps: https://medium.com/akeo-tech/step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-hyperledger-indy-64eeb524f558